# How to do url re-writing for MVC purpose in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This works fine on localhost:

```
#The RewriteEngine directive enables or disables the runtime rewriting engine.
RewriteEngine On

#This won't allow any folder to be accessible  if it's not having an index.php file
Options All -Indexes

#This will redirect user to http://localhost/awe/ if 404 or 403 error comes
ErrorDocument 404 http://192.168.1.6/app/
ErrorDocument 403 http://192.168.1.6/app/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The same gives me error on Godaddy.com server : `Error 500`

When I remove `Options All -Indexes` It use to show me 1st page as index.php exists there but doesn't show internal pages and shows `404` error because its being defined under my `Bootstrap`. Kindly suggect what needs to be done.

Also, I have put it into one of my subdomain and within one folder: So the path of my app is like this:

```
http://mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/myprojectname/app
```

So my `.htaccess` file I am putting in this folder only `http://mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/myprojectname/app`

Comment: Are you sure, that it's 505 error and not 500?

Comment: @user4035 I am so sorry, its `500` Error

Comment: Are you simply trying to get a RewriteRule to work on GoDaddy?  Hard to tell from your post.

Answer (score 1):

I think most likely you are getting the 500 error from GoDaddy because you have invalid IPs and path for your 404 handling route and you hit the 404 then everything blows up. Think of 500 as you broke something and 404 as it doesn't exist. Also you haven't defined a base for your rewrite which could be an issue as well.

Here is my advice, study some htaccess rules that are battle tested and known to work 100%, and build from there.

I suggest the most widely used ones in existance... https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Also they have examples for subfolders and subdomains.